# OpenSSL CMS encrypt in C++ and Objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, content-management-system, openssl

I'm encrypting a text (just a string) using OpenSSL's CMS library. I've implemented a cms encrypt method and when I call this in a C++ project (with the equal certificate and input string) it produces the following output:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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```

But when I copy the code into a objective-c Project (for iOS5) I get a "wrong" output which I can't decrypt anymore... This is the output:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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```

It's exactly the same code but produces two different outputs. To me the second output seems very strange because of the mane "AAAA" in base64 encoding. I guess this must be the part of the certificate. At the bottom is the encrypted input string and the begin of the certificate is equal but it changes strangely in the middle or end of the certificate.

Does anyone have a suggestion what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... the problem was a bug in the OpenSSL lib. When compiling for a certain architecture (i.e. i386) and using it in an x64 environment the `CMS_encrypt()` method produces the aforementioned wrong output. This bug results from some performance optimizations in assembler.

For further information see:
http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.cgi => *12. Why does OpenBSD-i386 build fail on des-586.s with "Unimplemented segment type"?*

I solved it by compiling OpenSSL with `no-asm` attribute.
`./Configure ... no-asm`

I had this problem because the library used for the iOS simulator needs a i386 architecture but Mac OSX uses x64. Simply compile it with `no-asm` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

S/MIME encoding generally works as follows:

1. Generate a random key
2. Encrypt your plaintext using that random key and a symmetric cipher (e.g. AES or triple-DES)
3. Encrypt the random key with a your recipient's public key and an asymmetric cipher (e.g. RSA)

You can use a command like "openssl asn1parse" to get a better idea of the internal structure of these messages, e.g.:

```
$ openssl asn1parse < blah.txt
```

Where *blah.txt* contains your S/MIME output, minus the MIME headers (i.e. starts with "MIAGCSq..."). Doing this, you get:

```
...
  196:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  207:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  209:d=5  hl=4 l= 256 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:08BB24600D266B784171CC0E6A6875E3F6F65EA4429816A41B13CC75014CA22432E3B52F18B438426AEE394D4CBF9DF4AF78E09715597760CD5F97C13F01C9F75391537F411A7B3606759D139CFCC87E4AAF579D8C4AE3FC4651CC9154D50CAAEBFB819F75B85FDFA3361B9659C3EBC6840EA1086B134BC44E7BF87596F989CD6260B58EADA4B09D09AF38B82B87D88226EABA9FD11617F60725E9444CA4123B64673EF6E97AC1CB819E3C9E01A40C7F85594D10655F8B5E6ABCC697692D6C4C01E874ED6214CF4B00D6891814C0A4DAECB9B20EE8BF23BCD3869E01B6655F3F1A0DEA0C306CCE7CD8B63F16316F047039B04E8F6731534A8C42EE3D96022126
  469:d=3  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE          
  471:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
  482:d=4  hl=2 l=  20 cons: SEQUENCE          
  484:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :des-ede3-cbc
  494:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:D5288E1B909F9EBC
  504:d=4  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]        
  506:d=5  hl=2 l=  24 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:F933A96AF388E6C01E278136920A3066E8C7163CA224CC20
  532:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:4E8686C88D083067
...
```

from your good output, and:

```
...
  196:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  207:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  209:d=5  hl=3 l= 252 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  464:d=3  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE          
  466:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
  477:d=4  hl=2 l=  20 cons: SEQUENCE          
  479:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :des-ede3-cbc
  489:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:00C9F0DF111FAB51
  499:d=4  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]        
  501:d=5  hl=2 l=  24 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:BB6A69A3361DF3AF40990F14636A55DC9B10B9A886D6B285
  527:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:E09B48E196386716
...
```

on your bad output. So this suggests that all those 'A's in your output are supposed to be the RSA-encrypted key, so the RSA encryption is failing somehow.

Without knowing more about your code, it's hard to say exactly what's going wrong, though. As a shot in the dark, I'd say make sure you remembered to call *OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()* (or something accomplishing the same purpose), but you probably already did, otherwise your code likely would fail everywhere, not just on iOS...